# How to create permalinks with OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I would like to know if there is any way to don't establish a determined center for the map. I mean, I would like to move and make zoom to my map and when I reload the page, my map shows with the center and zoom that I made before. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a permalink? OpenLayers 3 does not provide a control which automatically handles permalinks because it is very application-specific how the map state is encoded in a link.

But it's not too hard to implement it yourself. Every time the map is moved, you'd have to update the center and zoom-level in the URL:

```
map.on('moveend', function() {
  var view = map.getView();
  var center = view.getCenter();
  window.location.hash =
      view.getZoom() + ';' + center[0] + ';' + center[1];
});
```

Then, when creating your map, you'd have to parse the URL to get the center and zoom-level back:

```
var zoom = 2, center = [0, 0];

if (window.location.hash !== '') {
  var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
  var parts = hash.split(';');
  if (parts.length === 3) {
    zoom = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    center = [
      parseFloat(parts[1]),
      parseFloat(parts[2])
    ];
  }
}

var map = new ol.Map({
...
  view: new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: zoom
  })
```

These two links might also be helpful:

http://oobrien.com/2015/01/openlayers-3-and-datashine/ (-> Permalinks)

http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for me, when I zoom to a different extent and then copy and paste in another window it reverts back to the default. what am i missing

Comment: @kflaw Hard to guess without seeing what you did. I would recommend opening a new question with your code.